# cvCanny is not working in opencv 2.3

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I want to perform a canny edge detection in opencv 2.3,coding in c language. But when I am using cvCanny for the same purpose it gives an error as unresolved external symbol _CvCanny,though I have used a proper prototype of CvCanny.
Is there any library that i have forgot to include or what?

Regards,

Comment: can you post the error? make question with a little more effort..

Comment: Here is the error-
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvCanny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot link because you didn't add the correct path/ libraries to your project

Comment: Can you specify which libraries I have to add,as I have already added opencv_core230.lib and opencv_highgui230.lib.

Comment: canny is in the imgproc module

Comment: Thanks I added opencv_imgproc230.lib and the problem is solved.